# Applying color to multiple objects in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, creative-cloud, swatches

I have multiple objects that I would like to all have the same color. That way, when I change the color of the 'master' object, all the rest would also change.

I am sure this is straightforward, but I am struggling to find the answer.

Comment: You could use styles as a method to quickly update multiple objects. You'd have to create the style first however, which may not be as quick of a solution as you are looking for.